# Why does the compiler assign null to all fields in an async state machine after it is done

Tags: c#, async-await, state-machine

I was looking into code of async/await which the compiler generates e.g. the async state machine. However I did notice something *weird*. The compiler assigns `null` to all fields created by the user, which were locals before, right after it completes its work. Either after an exception occurs or the method simply finishes executing. I am kinda curious to why that happens, since to my knowledge this doesn't *really* improve *performance*.

See this [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGArAbgFgAodLbAOgBUALBOCAEwEsA7AcyNMxwBYuMgjCRQBmLACYMVOLADCAG2hQSAbxJCs4nADYsADiw6APABlmsY2xgA+GxgCycGDQD2jABRyIrAMZwFJRhmV1YqVwBrOFYMXxgASg0hVU1BJNSMADcIBAwFCxgMAF4MVjgAdwxzS2sbD3iBDLyCigBBRk9sBvTUns0UAE4jCgARAIgATw9sNFmAGliExoy+oXzYNo6PCW7iJuE9ppQAdmbYZYwAXxJLoA==) example.

Both after lowering the code which constructs the state machine you can see the null assigmnets.

```cs
// omitted for brevity

catch (Exception exception)
{
    <>1__state = -2;
    <list>5__2 = null;
    <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
    return;
}

<>1__state = -2;
<list>5__2 = null;
<>t__builder.SetResult(result);
```

As well as in the bare IL:

```
// omitted for bravity

catch [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Exception
{
    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_0098: stloc.3
    IL_0099: ldarg.0
    IL_009a: ldc.i4.s -2
    IL_009c: stfld int32 TestClass/'<Method>d__0'::'<>1__state'
    IL_00a1: ldarg.0
    IL_00a2: ldnull
    IL_00a3: stfld class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> TestClass/'<Method>d__0'::'<list>5__2'
    IL_00a8: ldarg.0
    IL_00a9: ldflda valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>> TestClass/'<Method>d__0'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_00ae: ldloc.3
    IL_00af: call instance void valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>>::SetException(class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Exception)
    IL_00b4: leave.s IL_00d1
} // end handler

IL_00b6: ldarg.0
IL_00b7: ldc.i4.s -2
IL_00b9: stfld int32 TestClass/'<Method>d__0'::'<>1__state'
// sequence point: hidden
IL_00be: ldarg.0
IL_00bf: ldnull
IL_00c0: stfld class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> TestClass/'<Method>d__0'::'<list>5__2'
IL_00c5: ldarg.0
IL_00c6: ldflda valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>> TestClass/'<Method>d__0'::'<>t__builder'
IL_00cb: ldloc.1
IL_00cc: call instance void valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>>::SetResult(!0)
```

I am pretty sure that this isn't because of some IL decompiling stuff. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Depending on the scope of the variables (like `<list>5__2`), it may do that so that the objects to which they refer no longer have any outstanding references. The would then make them eligible for garbage collection

Comment: @Flydog57 So its just a safe way to ensure that the state machines and its references do get garbage collected?

Comment: I don't know.  But, if you have a local variable (scoped to a function) that is the only variable that references an object, then, when the variable goes out of scope, the object will no longer have any live references and be bait for the garbage collector.  If you have a variable that isn't scoped locally, in an object that may still have live references, then it will keep the object to which it refers alive.  By explicitly setting that variable to null, you remove the reference to the object and the collector can do its thing.